# The white line on DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the density graph of solutions of a differential equation.

There are some white lines on the graph. I tested the points on the white lines, they all have expected values. I guess the white lines come from the UnitStep function in the equation. Is there any method to erase it properly?
[image]

I had tried `Exclusions -> None`, but the results becomes different and wried
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) option to increase the quality of the plot.

[image]

For instance, `PlotPoints->100`:

Note: You didn't supply a value for `x0` so I set `x0=0` below.

```
x0=0;
y0=1/Sqrt[2];
ga=1;
theta=Pi/2;
J=-Pi/2/eta;
sol=ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t]==-ga*x[t]-ga/2*(3*Exp[I*theta]*y[t-eta]*UnitStep[t-eta]+Exp[I*3*theta]*y[t-3 eta]*UnitStep[t-3 eta])-ga*Exp[I*2*theta]*x[t-2 eta]*UnitStep[t-2 eta]-J*I*y[t],y'[t]==-ga*y[t]-ga/2*(3*Exp[I*theta]*x[t-eta]*UnitStep[t-eta]+Exp[I*3*theta]*x[t-3 eta]*UnitStep[t-3 eta])-ga*Exp[I*2*theta]*y[t-2 eta]*UnitStep[t-2 eta]-J*I*x[t],x[t/;t<=0]==x0,y[t/;t<=0]==y0},{x,y},{t,-10,10},{eta}];

eta1=0.2;
omega=Pi/2/eta1;
IC[d_,ta_]=Abs[x[eta1][ta-(d+eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta-(d+eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta-(d+eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta-(d+eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta-(d-eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta-(d-eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta-(d-eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta-(d-eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta+(d-eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta+(d-eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta+(d-eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta+(d-eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta+(d+eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta+(d+eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta+(d+eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta+(d+eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta-(d+3*eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta-(d+3*eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta-(d+3*eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta-(d+3*eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta-(d-3*eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta-(d-3*eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta-(d-3*eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta-(d-3*eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta+(d-3*eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta+(d-3*eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta+(d-3*eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta+(d-3*eta1/2))])+x[eta1][ta+(d+3*eta1/2)]*Exp[-I*omega*(ta+(d+3*eta1/2))]*(UnitStep[ta-(ta+(d+3*eta1/2))]-UnitStep[-(ta+(d+3*eta1/2))])]^2/. sol;

Grid[{{DensityPlot[IC[d,t],{d,-1,1},{t,0,2},ColorFunction->"BlueGreenYellow",PlotLegends->Automatic,PlotRange->All,Exclusions->True,PlotPoints->100]
,Plot3D[IC[d,t],{d,-1,1},{t,0,2},ColorFunction->"BlueGreenYellow",PlotRange->All,Exclusions->True,PlotPoints->100]},{DensityPlot[IC[d,t],{d,-1,1},{t,0,2},ColorFunction->"BlueGreenYellow",PlotLegends->Automatic,PlotRange->All,Exclusions->False,PlotPoints->100],Plot3D[IC[d,t],{d,-1,1},{t,0,2},ColorFunction->"BlueGreenYellow",PlotRange->All,Exclusions->False,PlotPoints->100]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than only increasing `PlotPoints` you can also increase `MaxRecursion`, e.g., `PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4`